# Borrar campo si contiene caracteres diferentes a numérico EAN

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una tabla y una columna de codigos EAN como lo ven en el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito ejecutar un update para borrar el campo solo aquellas EAN que poseen caracteres distintos a numerico.

la linea que contiene el codigo: 84350995XXXXX, N/A y 84350994AAAAA esa linea debe ser borrada

Algo como esto pero no me funciona:

> tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set ean = '' where ean <> REGEXP '^[0-9]+$');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar [`NOT REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), que es exactamente lo que estas necesitando.

#### Ejemplo:

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set ean = '' where ean NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'");
```

Answer (score 1):

yo lo resolviería de la siguiente manera, necesitas hacer una consulta con una Regexp, para actualizar tus registros que contengan algo diferente de numero.
Te dejo un ejemplo.

MySQL REGEXP ejemplo
Suponga que desea encontrar todos los productos cuyos apellidos comienzan con el carácter A, B o C. Puede usar una expresión regular en la siguiente instrucción SELECT:

```
SELECT 
  productname
FROM
  products
WHERE
  productname REGEXP '^(A|B|C)'
ORDER BY productname;
```

En tu caso necesitas una Regexp que obtenga solo numeros: ^[0-9]*$

En [este](https://www.regextester.com/21) sitio web puedes probar tus Regexp,

Saludos

Comment: algo asi: tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set ean = '' where ean <> REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'); //// no funciona

Comment: Necesitas algo así `UPDATE table_name
   SET column_name = PREG_REPLACE('regex_match', 'replacement_value', column_name);`